# Call to undefined function gnupg_init()

Tags: php, gnupg

I have an AWS server with apache2 and PHP installed,
I want to use PGP for the encryption and decryption process, so i am trying to use below code

```
$res = gnupg_init();
```

but it is giving a below error

```
Call to undefined function gnupg_init()
```

I have tried installing this extension but no success,
can anyone help with the steps to get that above statement to work?

Comment: How have you tried to install the extension and what problems have you had with it.

Comment: Hello @NigelRen
I tried like sudo apt install gnupg and that produced below output

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libonig5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.